# Terraform: Is it possible to depend on only 1 resource in a list of resources?

Tags: terraform

Lets say that I am creating a set of AWS instances:

```
resource "aws_instance" "provision" {
  count = var.aws_azs
  ...
}
```

Then, in a separate null_resource to decouple the configuration step from the provisioning step:

```
resource "null_resource" "configure" {
  count = var.aws_azs
  depends_on = [aws_instance.provision[count.index]]
  ...
}
```

That dependency is illegal because depends_on requires a static reference. However, If I instead change it to `depends_on = ["aws_instance.provision"]`, then all of the configuration resources will be tainted if any of the instances are tainted. Is there a way to depend on only 1 instance in a list of resources?

Comment: Why not specifically access the element you want to depend on instead of attempting to depend on all of them?

Comment: Because it means manually creating resources for each element, which doesn't scale.

Comment: Ok so what you really want here is a set of `aws_instance` resources and a set of `null_resource` resources that have a one-to-one depending mapping by element; sort of like what you would see in an array to hash/dict conversion. If you want to do this and be DRY you probably would need to use an iterator which means >= 0.12.

Comment: Which we are. I'll look into iterators.

Answer (score 0):

The `depends_on` meta-argument does not interact with the tainting mechanism at all. It is used only to help Terraform select a suitable order to perform actions in.

Given a configuration like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "configure" {
  count      = var.aws_azs

  depends_on = [aws_instance.provision]
}
```

This just means that if a particular plan contains actions for both `aws_instance.provision` *and* `null_resource.configure` instances then all of the `aws_instance.provision` actions will be completed before starting any `null_resource.configure` actions. It will never cause any *additional* changes to be planned.

If your goal is to have the `null_resource.configure` instances be recreated when their corresponding `aws_instance.provision` instances are replaced, you can achieve that using `triggers` like this:

```
resource "null_resource" "configure" {
  count      = length(aws_instance.provision)

  triggers = {
    instance_id = aws_instance.provision[count.index].id
  }
}
```

In this case, it's the *value* of `aws_instance.provision[count.index].id` that is the decider: as long as that id doesn't change the `null_resource` won't be recreated. Because the `id` of an `aws_instance` changes only when it is recreated, `null_resource.configure` therefore won't re-run unless a specific corresponding index is recreated.

Having a reference to `aws_instance.provision` in the `triggers` expression also creates an implicit dependency, so Terraform will also still ensure that all of the `aws_instance.provision` work is complete before starting any `null_resource.configure` work, without the need to additionally specify `depends_on`.

Comment: My issue isn't with getting resource B to be handled after resource A through dependencies or triggers. My issue is blast radius. I want to be able to recreate only 1 instance of resource A and have that trigger only its corresponding instance of resource B to be recreated. Currently, with `depends_on = [aws_instance.provision]` in the example triggers the recreation of ALL instances of resource B. I also want to make sure that resource B is always recreated when its corresponding resource A is recreated.